# Why is UMAP used in combination with other Clustering Algorithm?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, dbscan, umap

I've noticed that UMAP is often used in combination with other clustering algorithms, such as K-means, DBSCAN, HDBSCAN. However, from what I've understood, UMAP can be used for clustering tasks. So why I've noticed people using it primarily as a dimensionality reduction technique?

Here an example of what I'm talking about:
[https://medium.com/grabngoinfo/topic-modeling-with-deep-learning-using-python-bertopic-cf91f5676504][1]

Am I getting something wrong? Can UMAP be used for clustering tasks alone? What are the benefits of using it in combination with other clustering algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned Noe, UMAP is 100% for dimensional reduction, ONLY to group similar data and separate different ones, THEN we apply a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN to identify those groups in the projected space.

Multi-dimensional reduction is the most difficult part because you need to detect similarities and differences among plenty of variables and then project them in a lower dimensional space, generally in 2D.

PCA was initially one of the first dimensional reduction algorithm (even if it is not exactly a dimensional reduction one) but it has a problem: it is linear.

UMAP is a non-linear reduction algorithm, meaning it can detect complex correlations between features. Therefore, it uses [Riemannian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) that are useful for representing complex, non-linear geometries that are difficult to capture with simple Euclidean distance measures.

UMAP constructs a weighted graph representation of the data, where the weights between each pair of data points are determined by a distance measure that considers the geometry of the Riemannian manifold. This graph is then optimized using a gradient-based algorithm to produce a low-dimensional embedding that preserves the high-dimensional geometric structure of the data.

More info:
https://pair-code.github.io/understanding-umap/

Answer (score 2):

UMAP is not for clustering. It is just for dimensionality reduction.

In the link you provided, UMAP is not used for clustering, just for dimensionality reduction. Specifically, they use [BERTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/index.html), which is a topic modeling technique that relies on UMAP. BERTopic takes sentence empeddings, applies dimensionality reduction with UMAP and does clustering with HDBSCAN.